# How to wrap content after \item[] in parenthesis?

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I want to redefine `\item[]` to make it work like:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt]{scrreprt}

\UsePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{notes}{description}{1}
\setlist[notes]{
  leftmargin=0.3\linewidth,labelsep=2em,
  itemsep=1.5ex,style=multiline,font=\normalfont
}

\def\removespecial{
  \catcode`\_=12
  \catcode`\^=12
  \catcode`\$=12
  \catcode`\%=12
  \catcode`\#=12
  \catcode`\&=12
  \catcode`\~=12
}

\begin{document}
\begin{notes}

\item[something]
{\removespecial\obeylines\obeyspaces
  ...some content...
}

\end{notes}
\end{document}
```

That is, to wrap the content after `\item[]` in parentheses so that I can use `\obeylines` etc inside. Without the parentheses, macros like `\obeylines` would affect the rest of the document and break some other commands. However, while manully adding the parentheses works, I can't figure out how to do it in macro (by redefining `\item[]` or some other ways). Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: @HarishKumar But this way it is still not wrapped? What is the \leavevmode for?

Comment: @HarishKumar That is to use parenthesis around \obeylines etc to limit its scope. {\obeylines sometext} makes \obeylines just affect sometext.

Comment: @HarishKumar No, it does affect the next item, just tested it.

Comment: Ok I take it back. No time for testing now. Hope somebody will pop up. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this extensively because I am not sure of your use case and your MWE doesn't give many clues. Still, I'm fairly confident that it works as you want because the MWE below produces:

[image]

In particular, note the spacing, line breaks and special characters that are behaving as you wanted. Moreover, given the comments above, I checked that your `\remove@special` doesn't remain in effect after the notes environment has closed, which is good.

The idea is to redefine `\item` inside a `notes` environment so that it inserts your special cat codes and `\obey*`'s inside a `\bgroup...\egroup` block. The first `\item` starts this group and the next one closes off the off the last group (using `\endLastItem`) and then starts the next `\item`-group. The only issue is that at the end of the `notes` environment we still need to close off the "special group" from the last `\item`. This is done by embedding your `notes` environment into another environment that takes care of this when is closes. So below the example actually appears inside a `Notes` environment.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{notes}{description}{1}
\setlist[notes]{
  leftmargin=0.3\linewidth,labelsep=2em,
  itemsep=1.5ex,style=multiline,font=\normalfont
}
\makeatletter
\def\remove@special{
  \catcode`\_=12
  \catcode`\^=12
  \catcode`\$=12
  \catcode`\%=12
  \catcode`\#=12
  \catcode`\&=12
  \catcode`\~=12
}
\let\realItem=\item
\let\endLastItem=\relax
\newcommand\specialItem[1][\relax]{\endLastItem%
   \ifx\relax#1\relax\realItem\else\realItem[#1]\fi%i
   \bgroup\remove@special\obeylines\obeyspaces
   \let\endLastItem\egroup}
\newenvironment{Notes}{\notes\let\item\specialItem}{\endLastItem\endnotes}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{Notes}
    \item[something]
    \item Another     item with    some

    special commands # _ $ % & ~
  \end{Notes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It worked for the posted question. However, after posting this question, I realized that I was in a more complicated situation than the one formulated in this question. And the method you posted here not completely work for that situation. If you don't mind please also have a look at [it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196624/xparse-macro-not-working-when-obeylines-is-in-effect) and help me with that more complicated situation.